# Delete files older than 7 days in perl

Tags: linux, perl

How to delete files from directories who are older than certain days (7 days) OR files who was created on any certain date?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with special file names (spaces, quotes) when piping to rm.

There is a safe alternative - the `-delete` option:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

That's it, no separate rm call and you don't need to worry about file names.

Replace `-delete` with -depth `-print` to test this command before you run it (`-delete` implies `-depth`).